# How to properly return one or two merged content_tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, refactoring

How to get rid of that duplicaiton in `if conditional`?

```
def set_caption(result)
  if result.respond_to?(:app_name)
    content_tag(:div, result.type_name, class: 'type-name') + 
      content_tag(:div, result.app_name, class: 'app-name')
  else
    content_tag(:div, result.type_name, class: 'type-name')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
def set_caption(result)
  rv = content_tag(:div, result.type_name, class: 'type-name')
  if result.respond_to?(:app_name)
    rv += content_tag(:div, result.app_name, class: 'app-name')
  end
  rv
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def set_caption(result)
  [:type_name, *(:app_name if result.respond_to?(:app_name))]
  .map{|name| content_tag(:div, result.send(name), class: name.hyphenize)}
  .inject(:+)
end
```

Or, assuming that `result.respond_to?(:type_name)` is always true:

```
def set_caption(result)
  [:type_name, :app_name]
  .map{|name| if result.respond_to?(name)
    content_tag(:div, result.send(name), class: name.hyphenize)
  end}.compact.inject(:+)
end
```

Comment: Wildly over-complex solution if I ever saw one. I would never want a co-worker to add something like this to a project I had to work on.